# How do I enable sound in Fedora 17?

Tags: fedora, audio

I did a minimal install of Fedora 17 some months ago and only until today did I try playing some audio with it only to find out that sound is not working.

How do I get the sound to work on Fedora 17?

My current setup is only using Xmonad as window manager, no desktop environment. So I would prefer the CLI way of installing/troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 7):

I scoured the web, following every suggestion I could find to get integrated Intel HDA audio to work under Fedora 17.   Nothing worked until I stumbled across this little gem:

`Add your user to the 'audio' group, then reboot`

From a shell prompt:

```
       sudo usermod -a -G audio yourUserName
```

After that, all I had to do was go to the Mixer control panel and select 'Playback: Internal Audio Analog Stereo (PulseAudio Mixer)'.

Comment: This is actually mandatory for ALSA users as well.

Answer (score 4):

To begin debugging this:

Install the alsa-utils and sox packages.

```
yum install alsa-utils sox
```

Now attempt to play a sample sound.

```
play /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

Take note of any error messages.

If you get no sound from the `play` command, then edit your question and [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) the output from:

```
dmesg | egrep -i "(alsa|sound)"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your sound is set to output over HDMI.  Check in your sound settings that the correct output is selected.